# why does my garage door sensor only work when i stand near it?

Tags: light, garage-door

Here is a video showing this phenomena.

The sensor quits blinking as i get close to it.

Why?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEvaifuUys0

Comment: Must be your electrifying smile and magnetic personality. It would be helpful if you would also describe in words what is happening. Questions that are full of information are easier to try and answer.

Comment: I will try, but this is really a puzzler to me. The red sensor light blinks continually and the door will not operate, indicating a problem in wiring, alignment, dirty lens etc, none of those are the problem. When I stand near or put my hand near the sensor, it stops blinking and the door works perfectly.

Comment: Garage door opener make and model?

Comment: Are you casting a shadow on the sensor?  Perhaps there's too much ambient light, saturating the detector, and your proximity shades it enough to work.

Comment: I would also double check the alignment.  I know you said you checked it, but these don't use RF or magnetic sensors so your body being physically close to it really shouldn't matter.

Comment: genie is is900/a

Comment: It really helps to watch the video, the room is totally dark, no shadows, it is not alignment because it stops blinking when i get near it. The thing to remember here is that when i get near it it STARTS working not the other way around.

Comment: To my mind it has got to be some sort of radio interferrence, it is like a old tv antenna, that starts getting reception when you get near or hold it.

Comment: it is a Genie model number is900/a

Comment: Before you came here for advise did you try to contact Genie to see if they could help. This is the kind of info i am referring to when i said "Questions that are full of information are easier to try and answer" **If you put all of the relevant info in your post then we do not have play 20 questions**.  I.E. what you have or have not done, the description of the problem, the make and model of the unit etc etc. It should be in the **body of the question**  and not  a string of comments.

Comment: I discovered the problem. The sensor was getting interference from the other door sensor shown to the left (has green ight). So i switched the sensors for the other door to position them so that the two red sensors (one for each door) are back to back. Problem solved. Thanks to the Genie Company Support Line for this information.